# How do I pass the objects retrieved from the localstorage into a DOM using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, data-structures

I am trying to pass all the data saved in the localStorage into the DOM using innerHTML. However, `showCollections()` doesn't return all the data in the retrieved in the local storage after clicking on the submit button or after reloading the page. It only returns the last item in the `collectionObj` array.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
//get form values 
// create an object of the form values
//create an empty array
//append object of the form values to the empty array
//display array object values

showCollection();

var getButton = document.getElementById('clickIt');
var collectionTitle = document.getElementById("title");
var collectionDescription = document.getElementById('describe')


getButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var collections = {
        title: collectionTitle.value,
        description: collectionDescription.value
    }

    let webCollections = localStorage.getItem('collectx');
    if(webCollections == null){
        var collectionObj = []
        alert('storage is empty')
    }
    else{
        collectionObj = JSON.parse(webCollections);
    }
    collectionObj.push(collections);
    localStorage.setItem("collectx", JSON.stringify(collectionObj));
    showCollection()
});


function showCollection(){
    let webCollections =  localStorage.getItem('collectx')
    if(webCollections == null){
        var collectionObj = []
        alert('storage is empty')
    }
    else{
        collectionObj = JSON.parse(webCollections);
    }
    let html= ''
    var demos = document.getElementById('demo');
    collectionObj.forEach(function(item, index){
        html = `<p> this is a description ${item.title} and description: ${item.description} </p>`
      })
      demos.innerHTML = html
   
    
}
```

```html
    
    <form id="forms">
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Collection name">
        <br>
        <br>
         <input id="describe" type="text" placeholder="Description">
        <button id="clickIt"> Submit </button>
      </form>
      
     <div id="demo">

     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to add a '+' sign,

```js
html += `<p> this is a description ${item.title} and description: ${item.description} </p>
```

This will render all the content onto the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You might use [insertAdjacentHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add each item, like:

```js
showCollection();

function showCollection() {
  const
    demo = document.getElementById('demo'),
    collection = simulateRetrievingCollection();

  collection.forEach((item) => {
    const html = `<p>${item.title}: ${item.description}</p>`;
    demo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  });
}

function simulateRetrievingCollection() {
  return [{
      title: "title1",
      description: "description1"
    },
    {
      title: "title2",
      description: "description2"
    },
    {
      title: "title3",
      description: "description3"
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```